# Python Scrapy - how to call variable from another spider method?

Tags: scrapy, python-3.7

So Im trying to learn scrapy and for learning project I want to scrape this site item names (from just 1 category atm) https://www.killertools.com/Dent-Removal-Aluminum-Steel_c_11.html and then enter those item urls and grab description text.

I already got some suggestion to write 2 spiders but I dont know how to fetch data from variable in parse method from first spider into second spider to populate start_urls.

This is where I'm at:

```
import scrapy


class Names(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'killernames'

    start_urls = ['https://www.killertools.com/Dent-Removal-Aluminum-Steel_c_11.html?viewall=1',]

    def parse(self, response):
        self.detail = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "product-item")]/div[@class="name"]/a/@href').getall()

        for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="name"]'):
            yield {
                'name': item.xpath('./a/text()').extract_first(),
                'url': item.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first(),
                 }

class Detail(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'killerdetail'

    start_urls = []

    for item in self.detail: (I dont know how to get it from first spider)
        url = 'https://www.killertools.com/' + item
        start_urls.append(url)



    def parse(self, response):

        for item in response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]'):
            yield {
                   'detail': item.xpath('./p/strong/text()').extract_first(),
                  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using two spiders, you can follow the links onto the individual pages using one spider. First a few points on creating spiders, followed by some concepts you need to understand to do this type of scrape. Then the code example and explanation below.

### Code Review

- Use `get()` instead of `extract_first()`, it's more concise, will always give you a string and scrapy docs suggest it
- Don't confuse using `getall()` with `extract()`. Sometimes extract() will give you a list or a string, `getall()` will always give you a list.
- Use items dictionary rather than yielding a dictionary. Particularly in this case where the data is not clean.

### Concepts to know

#### Items

An items dictionary is scrapy's inhoues way of collecting data. It allows you to alter the data coming in and outputs later on if needed. It's more flexible than yielding a dictionary.
To start of using items you need to include the field names in items.py that you want to use as potential columns. In this case name,URL, description.

#### items.py

import scrapy

```
class KillerItem(scrapy.Item):
   
    name = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
```

We are creating an KillerItem class that subclasses scrapy.Item. We are instantiating the Field() object and calling it the names we want to yield as columns.

You also need to include in your spider script

```
from ..items import KillerItem
```

This is a relative import, .. means parent directory, where items.py lives.
The KillerItem is a class that needs to be instantiated to create the items dictionary. We do that by the code below.

```
items = KillerItem()
```

Which creates the items dictionary, but it has the keys that correspond to our field names we created in items.py. So we can now fill these keys with values that correspond to the data we want. In this case, name,URL and description.

```
items['name] = ...
```

When we are done populating the items dictionary we must use `yield items`. This is important as we want to yield when we have the name,URL and description for each individual page.

#### Use of meta argument

You can transfer variables from function to function via the meta argument of a scrapy request. The meta argument accepts a dictionary, we in this case want to transfer the items dictionary we create in the parse function with name and URLs. We want to populate this items dictionary with the descriptions from individual pages. We do this by creating a dictionary with a key, of our choosing and then the value is our items dictionary we defined when we instantiated the KillerItems class.

```
meta= {'items',items}
```

To access this items dictionary in the next function, ie where the parsing of the individual pages occurs. We can access through the response

```
items = response.meta['items']
```

We're being consistent with our items variable, and accessing the value via meta['items']

With that now explained we can go onto the code example.

### Code Example

```
import scrapy
from ..items import KillerItem

class Names(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'killernames'

    start_urls = ['https://www.killertools.com/Dent-Removal-Aluminum-Steel_c_11.html?viewall=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        

        for item in response.xpath('//div[@class="name"]'):
            items = KillerItem()
          
            items['name'] = item.xpath('./a/text()').get()
            items['url'] = 'https://www.killertools.com/' + item.xpath('./a/@href').get()
            

            
            yield response.follow(url=items['url'], callback=self.page, meta={'items':items})
           
    def page(self,response):
       
        items = response.meta['items']
        base = response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]')
        if base.xpath('./p/strong/text()') and base.xpath('./p/span/text()'):
            items['description'] = base.xpath('./p/strong/text()').get().replace('\xa0','') + base.xpath('./p/span/text()').get().replace('\xa0','')
        elif base.xpath('./p/strong/text()'):
            items['description'] = base.xpath('./p/strong/text()').get().replace('\xa0','')
        elif base.xpath('./p/span/text()'):
            items['description'] = base.xpath('./p/span/text()').get().replace('\xa0','')
        elif base.xpath('./span/text()'):
            items['description'] = base.xpath('./span/text()').get().replace('\xa0','')
        elif base.xpath('./h3/text()'):
            items['description'] = base.xpath('./h3/text()').get().replace('\xa0','')
        else:
            items['description'] = base.xpath('./text()').get()
        yield items
```

### Explanation

Not much has changed in the parse function, we create the values using your xpath selectors for name and URL. We populate the items key corresponding to the field names we created in items.py.

. We use the response.follow method, in the arguments, we specify the URL which is items['url'] for each iteration of the for loop and the callback function which we call `self.page`, we also have the meta argument which creates a simple dictionary of name items and the value of our items dictionary created to transfer our items dictionary to the parse function.

Within the pages function, we then have quite a lot of elif statements because the description of each page is not consistent, unfortunately.

Lastly we yield the items dictionary now we have the description for each individual page.

You didn't really specify the description bullet points but you should have enough to go and get that extra date if you needed it.

Comment: You Sir are a GOD among men! Sadly I don't have a rep to vote this up yet but You basicly saved me probably more than a week of reading documentation that I hardly understand so probably even 1 more week of blind testing what does what. 4 months ago I started watching some ultimate beginner things on python like print("Hello World!") level stuff. Still a lot of concepts confuse me as hell, especially in frameworks where stuff work in backend. So its easiest for me to learn by dissecting working examples. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Could you tick my answer as the accepted one on the left hand side of the answer? Thanks! 

Python is difficult but keep at it. It does get easier.